# PHP request usage

Tags: php, swift

I have read up quite a bit about the request method now, and i found a example that supplies this php example :

```
<?php
  // Read request parameters
  $firstName= $_REQUEST["firstName"];
  $lastName = $_REQUEST["lastName"];// Store values in an array
  $returnValue = array(“firstName”=>$firstName, “lastName”=>$lastName);
  // Send back request in JSON format
echo json_encode($returnValue); 
?>
```

i have written a IOS app in swift that sends data to this php, i will then use the website and write the data received to a textfile on the server, is the $_Request method the correct method ?

IOS part ( not complete code ) that sends data to the website :

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost/test.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "firstName=Neil&lastName=Johnson"
```

Note : this code does not seam to work ( Undefined index at line 4, 5 and 6 but im not sure why as i cant use a isset method here as some threads have stated to remove the error)

Thank you in regards

Comment: Try `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`

Comment: The $_REQUEST superglobal contains the contents of $_GET and $_POST so it should work anyway

Comment: Check your quotes. And install a proper text editor/ide with syntax highlighting support

Comment: You should use $_POST and use standard double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) is not a "method", it's a "superglobal variable". Methods are called using parentheses(). Arrays (such as this) are accessed via square brackets[].

"Undefined index" means you're trying to access an array element that doesn't exist, which suggests to me that you aren't POSTing the firstName and/or lastName correctly to PHP.

Generally you shouldn't be composing your POST message manually. Isn't there something in iOS/Swift to form-encode your variables? If not, did you set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? That could be it as well.

Lastly, your quotes on this line

```
$returnValue = array(“firstName”=>$firstName, “lastName”=>$lastName);
```

Are weird. You need to use the standard `"` found on your keyboard. If you're copy-pasting something from a blog, WordPress likely mangled them for you.

Comment: yeah sorry only saw that quotes now, weird. my data is successfully being sent to the website now so thanks for the help ! cheers

Comment: so i got it working pretty good with using the $_request variable ... i am now able to send values to the website, can this also be used to retrieve data from the website to my device ? my next step is to be able to retrieve values as well ! thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

This one confuses quite a few people so I'm going to attempt to explain this as objectively as possible.

PHP has a few [super global variables](http://php.net/language.variables.superglobals) which are automatically populated based on certain conditions.

## When to use `$_POST`

You should use the `$_POST` superglobal to access your data when you *expect* the HTTP request method to the resource to be `POST` and nothing else. The `POST` request verb is typically used for non-idempotent requests (*like checking out a shopping cart or adding a post to a web forum*).

Note that `$_POST` only populates when the `Content-type` header is `www-form-urlencoded` or `multi-part` encoded. Otherwise you will have to check `php://input` since PHP probably won't decode it into `$_POST`. PHP also mangles the names a bit (*e.g. it replaces spaces and dots with underscores*). See [Handling External Variables](http://php.net/language.variables.external) for more details.

## When to use `$_GET`

Adversely, you should use `$_GET` when expect the input to be a part of the query string or in forms where you've explicitly set the request `method` to `GET`. Notice this doesn't necessarily mean you expect the HTTP request verb to be `GET` every time.

## When to use `$_REQUEST`

You use `$_REQUEST` when you actually don't care whether the HTTP request verb was `POST` or `GET`, because `$_REQUEST` combines both into one array. In this case it's important to recognize that if the same name is populated both in `POST` and `GET` that there is [a specific order in which they will be overwritten](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.variables-order).

---

It's always better to be explicit as in a RESTful approach you would rarely rely on `$_REQUEST`. In your case you seem to be explicitly sending a `POST` request so I would stick with `$_POST` in this case. But you very well may send `POST` request and still expect the input in the query string, in which case `$_GET` is appropriate. I've very rarely seen a real need for `$_REQUEST` in the majority of cases.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It explains when it is appropriate to get the input from which super global without making assumptions about the OP's implementation. For example, it explains that `$_POST` expects a url-encoded Content-type. It also explains `variable_order` configuration when dealing with `$_REQUEST`. It also explains how external names can be mangled in `$_POST`/`$_GET`/`$_REQUEST` keys. In what way do you feel that this does *not* answer the question? I'm happy to modify the answer.

Comment: The additional information you have provided is useful, but his problem was an error of Undefined Index.  mpen above has pointed this out to the OP.  Perhpas modify your answer to point out that mpen has solved the issue and you are providing further information on the $_REQUEST variable.

Comment: I was in the process of typing up this answer before I saw any other answers submitted. It was unclear what caused the undefined index error so I included relevant information that would help address that. I don't see any reason why this does not help address the question, however.